# Do Klingon women use their father's or mother's name?

Tags: star-trek, klingon

So most Klingons seem to refer to themselves as "[name], son/daughter of [parent's name]". For Klingon males, we know it's their father's name. But I've never been able to determine if Klingon females use their father's name or their mother's. Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Are the Duras sisters ever referred to as "daughter of Ja'rod"?

Comment: @OrangeDog - No. His only mention in the show is in Sins of the Father (*"Ja'rod, father of Duras"*).

Comment: "most Klingons seem to refer to themselves as "[name], son/daughter of [parent's name]".  <- Are you sure about that?

Comment: @einpoklum - There are lots of examples in the shows and novels.

Comment: @Valorum: Yes, but there are plenty of Klingons who just go by one name. Now, you could say that the parent name is still "in the background" somehow, but then you could say the same about many cultures.

Comment: @einpoklum - When introducing themselves formally, every Klingon (except Alexander) uses the form "son of/daughter of". It's not quite so clear cut when it's a more informal situation

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Typically a daughter uses the name of her father. There are a few examples.**

From [DS9: *Sons And Daughters*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sons_and_Daughters_(episode)),

> **WORF:** *Who offers their life for the Empire?*
>
> **N'GAREN:** *N'Garen, daughter of Tse'Dek!*
>
> **KATOGH:** *Katogh, son of Ch'Pok!*
>
> **KOTH:** *Koth, son of Larna!*
>
> **DORAN:** *Doran, daughter of W'Mar!*

With confirmation from the [*Star Trek Encyclopedia*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia) that Tse'Dek is N'Garen's father

> **Tse’Dek:** Klingon warrior, **father of N’Garen**. (“Sons and Daughters” [DS9]).

and confirmation from *[StarTrek.com](https://intl.startrek.com/database_article/wmar)* that W'mar is Doran's father.

> **W'mar: Klingon male.** W'mar's teenaged daughter, Doran, was transferred to the Rotarran in 2374 and joined General Martok's dispirited crew.

Other examples include Sirella (*"daughter of [Linkasa](https://books.google.nl/books?id=cbYf2l7gczUC&lpg=PT2494&ots=lHlRJ1hYXv&dq=%22linkasa%22%20star%20trek%20encyclopedia&pg=PT2494#v=snippet&q=linkasa&f=false)"*) from *[DS9: You are Cordially invited](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/You_Are_Cordially_Invited_(episode))*, mentioned in [LogicDictates' answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/122024/logicdictates).

---

Moving down the food-chain, there are endless examples in the EU novels.

> Without meaning to, he [Kahless] began whispering the words he would have
> spoken. "I pledge my heart and my hand to you, **Kellein, daughter of
> [Lord] Vathraq,** and no other. I am your mate for the rest of my days."
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Kahless](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kahless_(novel))</sup></sub>

and

> “I do not speak those words lightly,” Wol added. “I have known many great warriors in my time.” She hesitated. “I was not always as I am now. Once I was **Eral, daughter of B’Etakk** of the House of Varnak.” <sub><sup>(B'Ettakk is referred to by Eral as "*Father*" later in the book)</sup></sub>
>
> <sub><sup>[IKS Gorkon: A Good Day to Die](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/A_Good_Day_to_Die)</sup></sub>

etc.

Answer (score 11):

#### It seems the father's name is used in relation to both Klingon males and females.

In the DS9 episode, "[You Are Cordially Invited](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/You_Are_Cordially_Invited_(episode))", [General Martok](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Martok) introduced his wife, [Sirella](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sirella), as:

> *... Sirella, daughter of Linkasa.*

The *[Star Trek Encyclopedia's](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia)* entry on [Linkasa](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Linkasa) reads as follows:

> Linkasa. Klingon Warrior. **Father of Sirella**. ("You are Cordially Invited" [DS9]).

Sirella also named her twenty-third maternal grandmother, [Shenara](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shenara), as:

> *... Shenara, daughter of Emperor Reclaw in the Second Dynasty.*

The *Star Trek Encyclopedia's* entry on [Emperor Reclaw](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Reclaw_(Second_Dynasty)) reads as follows:

> Second Klingon Dynasty. Period in Klingon history in which Emperror Reclaw ruled the empire. The Second Dynasty ended when General K'Trelan assassinated **Emperor Reclaw and his family** and plunged the empire into thr Dark Time. ("You Are Cordially Invited" [DS9]).

As noted in [Valorum's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241500/do-klingon-women-use-their-fathers-or-mothers-name/241503#241503), in the DS9 episode, "[Sons and Daughters](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sons_and_Daughters_(episode))", [N'Garen](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/N%27Garen) and [Doran](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Doran,_daughter_of_W%27mar) introduced themselves thusly:

> **N'GAREN:** *N'Garen, daughter of Tse'Dek!*

> **DORAN:** *Doran, daughter of W'Mar!*

The *[Star Trek Encyclopedia's](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/526.htm)* entry on [Tse'Dek](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tse%27Dek) reads as follows:

> Tse'Dek. Klingon Warrior, **father of N'Garen**. ("Sons and Daughters" [DS9]).

[StarTrek.com's](https://www.startrek.com/) entry on [W'Mar](https://www.startrek.com/database_article/wmar) reads as follows:

> W'mar
>
> **Klingon male.** W'mar's teenaged daughter, Doran, was transferred to the Rotarran in 2374 and joined General Martok's dispirited crew.

And in the *Voyager* episode, "[Prophecy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Prophecy_(episode))", [Kohlar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kohlar) named his mother, [Talij](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Talij), as:

> *... Talij, daughter of K'Rene.*

StarTrek.com's entry on [K'Rene](https://www.startrek.com/database_article/krene) reads as follows:

> K'rene
>
> **Father of Talij**, whose name was invoked during a "Plea for the Dead" by Captain Kohlar. The prayer is meant to honor those warriors who have fallen in the name of Kahless.

In the same episode, [B'Elanna Torres](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/B%27Elanna_Torres) named her maternal grandmother, [L'Naan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/L%27Naan), as:

> *... L'Naan, daughter of Krelik.*

StarTrek.com's entry on [Krelik](https://www.startrek.com/database_article/krelik) reads as follows:

> Krelik
>
> **Great-grandfather of B'Elanna Torres**, on the Klingon side.

Comment: Please demonstrate that Linkasa is a man's name, other than with an uncited link from Memory alpha

Comment: The Memory Alpha stub you've linked to seems to conclude that Linkasa is male on the assumption that the father's name is indeed used by daughters. There still doesn't seem to be any actual evidence supporting that assumption.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - There is, just not on Memory Alpha. For that you need to dig a little deeper; https://books.google.nl/books?id=cbYf2l7gczUC&lpg=PT2494&ots=lHlRJ1hYXv&dq=%22linkasa%22%20star%20trek%20encyclopedia&pg=PT2494#v=snippet&q=linkasa&f=false

Comment: Seconded this is a highly relevant example but to demonstrate how indeterminate the practise is as Linkasa is unknown.

Comment: I've edited the answer to add a better source, but it appears the information provided in Linkasa's Memory Alpha page was directly sourced from the Star Trek Encyclopedia. They just neglected to indicate that.

Comment: Torres is probably not a good example. Her father was human so it wouldn't make much sense for her to use his side of the family when naming herself in the Klingon fashion.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - Torres wasn't naming herself in the example I gave though. She was naming her maternal _grandmother_, whose parents, presumably, were both Klingon.

Comment: @LogicDictates - If I had a penny for every missing source on Memory Alpha, I wouldn't need to work again.